# Detached Result of laravel sync() is not an Array

Tags: laravel, lumen

With Lumen 5.6, I do:

```
try {
    $categories = $this->request->categoriesSelected; // [1,2,3]
    return $tournament->categories()->sync($categories);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
         return response()->json($e->getMessage(), 422);
    }
```

Then, In my checkbox category list, I check 2 boxes, and uncheck 2 boxes, and I am expecting a result like:

```
attached: Array(2), detached: {…}, updated: Array(0)}
attached: (2) [3, 4]
detached: (2) [2, 6]
updated: []
```

but instead, detached comes as on object, an not an array, which make it quite difficult to make a loop on it, is it normal ?

```
attached: Array(2), detached: {…}, updated: Array(0)}
attached: (2) [3, 4]
detached: {1: 2, 2: 6}
updated: []
```

It is important to say that it is doing the job in DB, removing 2 categories, and adding 2, but to update my views with Angular, I need the modified data, and it is not the format I was expecting.

Comment: Sync with the new array(attached) it will remove the old one and new one

Comment: I didn't understand what you are saying :(

Comment: Where are you getting attached and detached from?